# Correct .env file with serverless-dotenv-plugin

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-plugins

I'm using the following as a custom `serverless-dotenv-plugin` plugin configuration:

`custom:
  dotenv:
    path: .env-${opt:stage, 'local'}`

But what I'm really trying to get is that the environment be loaded from `.env` file when I give no arguments and `.env.staging` file when I use `staging` as a CLI argument.

I don't know how this can be reflected in `path` above. Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the author of serverless-dotenv-plugin. There was a logistical problem when trying to dynamically load env files from the provider or other options. I have since updated the plugin however so that you can dynamically load env files based what environment is set.

For example, if you run "NODE_ENV=production sls deploy" it will look for a file called .env.production. If it is not found, it will fallback to .env.

See the README for more detail https://github.com/infrontlabs/serverless-dotenv-plugin

Answer (score 3):

I got your use case to work by just using the normal [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) plugin.

In my `serverless.yaml`, I specify environment variables to be loaded from a file based on the `stage` parameter (`dev` is default):

```
provider: 
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  environment:
    FOO: ${file(./config.${self:provider.stage}.js):getEnvVars.FOO}
    BAR: ${file(./config.${self:provider.stage}.js):getEnvVars.BAR}
```

---

Then one file per stage that loads the environment variables from the right `.env file`:

`config.dev.js`:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/dev.env'});
const config = require('./environmentVariables.js');
module.exports.getEnvVars = config.getEnvVars;
```

`config.production.js`:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/production.env'});
const config = require('./environmentVariables.js');
module.exports.getEnvVars = config.getEnvVars;
```

---

Instead of exporting every environment variables in each of the above config files, I created a helper file for this (`environmentVariables.js`):

```
module.exports.getEnvVars = () => ({
    FOO: process.env.FOO,
    BAR: process.env.BAR
});
```

---

Last but not least the `.env` files containing the actual variables. I named the files `dev.env` and `production.env`.

```
FOO=foo
BAR=bar
```

---

It works like a charm, the only downside being that you have to edit several different files whenever you want to add a new environment variable.

Comment: Why are you requiring staging.env inside config.staging.js but then you say the file is named production.env?

Comment: Thanks for spotting Adrián, it has been corrected now.